# How do I make my laptop's mute key work in OpenSUSE 11.1

Tags: linux, opensuse

I just installed openSUSE 11.1 and I am pretty psyched to give everything a go but I have noticed that my volume and mute buttons don't seem to be working.  I am sort of new so I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using KDE, you can use [KMix](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdemultimedia/kmix/index.html) to configure custom keys to toggle volume levels and mute.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're on GNOME, go to the Control Center -> Keyboard Shortcuts and setup your keys there. =)

Answer (score 0):

It could be something with the PCM too. Can i ask the model of the laptop?
Keytouch Is in a common repo, might solve the problem too.